# WordPress: can themes come with images out of the box?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to wordpress and i wanted to start up with a new theme, but i can't find a theme that comes with images incorporated, every theme i tried came differently than the preview of it.

My question is: are there any themes that come with the images shown in their sites or do i always have to import them after importing the theme?

Comment: All the themes come with their own import file.

Comment: What does that mean? Does that mean that it is possible to include images in there to be imported to my site?

Comment: When purchasing a theme, always read the Small Print to find out exactly what you are getting. Many themes will display images as to give you an idea of what the theme may look like but may not actually come with the theme, due to licencing restrictions.

Comment: I did something close to that, got in touch with the developers themselves, which is also a good idea because it gives you right away an idea of how good is costumer service. But thanks for the info, will certainly be useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is possible to import everything from a theme demo.

The way to do it is by installing the one click demo import plugin and upload the demo files with the plugin. those demo files have to be made available by the theme developer, which aren't always.